# Keithley 2450 Charge/Discharge adjusting appropiate V and I

Tags: battery-charging, discharge

I'm using Keithley 2450 model for charging/discharging battery. My aim is to find charge/discharge characteristics of 100mAH 9V battery. In the following link, they have described discharge characteristics of 2300mAH AA battery.

[Rechargeable Battery Charge/Discharge 
Cycling Using the Keithley Model 2450 
SourceMeter
®
 SMU Instrument](http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/RechargeableBattery_2450_AN1.PDF)

The first question during this process is, how can I adjust the proper values for X Voltage batteries and Y ilimit level (current). The second question is what is (smu.source.range = 2) in the codes, would I also adjust it for different voltages?

Comment: For charging/discharging you need to apply a constant current, you would want to set a voltage limit, not a current limit. Range sounds like 2V, you probably want the 20V range.

Comment: @SpaceCadet Can you please clarify this. Why I need 20V range? Which parameters should be changed in the code? How can I specify/calculate the correct values for corresponding rechargeable battery? My aim is to draw a characteristic curve for the battery.

Comment: If your on a 2V range thats not going to work (at least for the measurement) on a 9V battery. I assume you are referring to your TSP code snippet, you should upload the complete code but I think you need to set 'smu.source.range = 20'

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've checked the TSP code example in the appendix in the application note.

I'm not certain but I think at least you need to change smu.source.range from 2 to 20 (to set a 20V range). Then determine your charge rate (0.2C is in the example i.e. 0.2(C) x 2.3(AH) = 460e-3 (A)) and set this value for the smu.source.ilimit.level & smu.measure.range.

So for your 0.1Ah battery 0.2C would be 20mA.